# How to populate the SWT table with database content?

Tags: java, mysql, swt

I am using PhpMyAdmin to save my data in database. I have a SWT table to populate with database content.

I tried below code. which prints the server data perfectly in console but it doesn't populate in my SWT table.

here is my code..

```
public static void fetchDatafromDB(String StartIndex, String FinalIndex) {
    try {
        Class.forName(GlobalVariables.SQL_driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(GlobalVariables.DB_url + GlobalVariables.DB_name, GlobalVariables.DB_Username, GlobalVariables.DB_password);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT  `From`, `To`, `IDno`, `TimeStamp` FROM `callsheet` WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '" + StartIndex + "' AND '" + FinalIndex + "'";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                // System.out.print(rs.getString(i));
                item.setText(i, rs.getString(i));
            }
            // System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (Exception P) {
        P.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting error in `setText()` line. Something similar happened when i was trying to print the `ID` no (RFID) in TextField(SWT).

Could you provide some specific solution for above problem please?

Following Errors occurred.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java2MySql.fetchDatafromDB(java2MySql.java:200)
at vehicleUserLog.NewVehicleCallSheet$6.widgetSelected(NewVehicleCallSheet.java:618)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at vehicleUserLog.NewVehicleCallSheet.open(NewVehicleCallSheet.java:167)
at java2MySql.ReadFromDB(java2MySql.java:72)
at java2MySql.SignInParser(java2MySql.java:107)
at ReportWindow.verifyfromDB(ReportWindow.java:294)
at ReportWindow$1.widgetSelected(ReportWindow.java:211)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at ApplicationLauncher.<init>(ApplicationLauncher.java:18)
at ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:30)
```

Comment: What is the error which you are getting in setText()? Could you please post the exception trace?

Comment: Which is line 200? You are incrementing `i` twice in the for loop.

Comment: line 200 is setText line. and double increment of i shouldn't effect the output. only the table content(column value) will get changed.

Comment: @user3431551 Where does `item` come from?

Comment: @Baz That is instance of TableItem. I haven't mentioned that line

Comment: @user3431551 Can you check if it's `null`?

Comment: @ Baz Thanks.it worked. Now I am getting some problem with tabling the DB content in  my swt table. What my program does, is that, it sets the entire content in one row (one by one manner) but I want the next row of DB table should be tabled in next row of SWT table. Could you suggest something about this?